# Scale images before upload

Tags: asp.net

I have upload control on my asp.net (C#) page, I always upload pictures. Is there any way to scale images before I upload ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do something like flash on the client to do this, [have a look here](http://www.adylevy.com/index.php/2009/06/07/client-side-image-resize-flash-cs4-filereferencedata/) and [here](http://www.resize-before-upload.com/) for examples.

It can't be done in JavaScript, etc...you'll need something with a bit more file system access, e.g. Flash, Silverlight, JavaApplet, etc.  But seeing as there are premade flash solutions out there, that's the route I'd take.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of solutions to your issue are below, since you haven't really specified how/where exactly you want to handle the image scaling.
http://upload.thinfile.com/image/
http://www.resize-before-upload.com/